# Ionic 5 Angular Sqlite: Uncaught in Promise

Tags: angular, database, sqlite, ionic-framework, promise

I am trying to create database in ionic 5 Angular but getting `Uncaught (in promise)` error when calling `.then()` method

[image]

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Error is in createDB() function which is getting called in constructor

```js
export class UniversalService {
    private database: SQLiteObject;
    employeelist = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    private dbReady: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

    constructor(
        private plt: Platform,
        private sqlite: SQLite,
        private sqlPorter: SQLitePorter,
    ) {
        this.plt.ready().then(() => {
            return this.createDB()
        });
    }

    createDB() {
        this.sqlite.create({
            name: 'emp.db',
            location: 'default'
        })
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
GETTING ERROR HERE
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
                this.database = db;
                alert("created!!")
            })
            .catch(e => {
                alert("error " + JSON.stringify(e))
            });
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Cordova-sqlite-storage can only be used on a native device (iOS/Android/Electron), that said unfortunately you can't use it in the browser.